# Copy everything from one schema to another in Oracle, but only the first n rows

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to recreate the complete structure of multiple very large schemas (size in GB/TB) in another schema, but when filling the tables I only want the first n rows.

Right now I am using the following statement to copy the tables but this works only if there are no foreign key constraints.

```
create table DEV_OWN.mytable as select * from TEST_OWN.mytable where rownum < 10
```

I want to make a script that loops through all tables and copies the first n rows or maybe more or less if it is dependent on a foreign key, and also the indexes, views, packages, stored procedures and preferrably everything else so that the resulting schema is a replica of the originial but with only a limited number or records.

Since I have to run this script often I would like it to be as optimal as possible.

Comment: I would suggest you to export/import the schema and then delete redundant data, so that the constraints will preserve integrity. Finding a way to pick the minimum number of rows from each table, respecting all the constraints, is not a trivial job.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have multiple very large databases with Gigabytes/Terrabytes of data and I would like to have an optimal script. I edited the question to reflect this better.

Answer (score 1):

As @Aleksej has suggested, you can export the schema and then import it again
Alternatively, you can use Execute immediate to do this.

you can access the system views, such as
`ALL_TABLES`, `all_indexes`, `all_triggers`.
This will allow you to build dynamic sql instructions that you can execute with `execute immediate` command, but this way is more complicated the to Export and Import the hole schema.

Here is a simple example for creating and filling the table

```
declare
  v_new_schema varchar2(100) := 'DEV_OWN';
begin
  for rec in (select * from all_tables)    
  loop
    execute immediate ('create table '||v_new_schema||'.'|| rec.table_name ||' as select * from '||rec.owner||'.'|| rec.table_name ||' where rownum < 10');
  end loop;
end;
/
```

In this example, only the tables without contraint, triggers, or anything else belonging to it are created.

If you need it all, then it's actually easier to dump a Schema.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to improve on this but am still unsure how to handle the foreign key constraints.

Comment: there also a view where you can find all constraints  `ALL_CONSTRAINTS`.

Answer (score 0):

I think best solution for your case is make an expdp with a where clause and then make an impdp.

Comment: (This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer, or just post it as a comment to the question).

Comment: Is there a way to generate that where clause based on foreign keys?